# RelatedObjectDoesNotExist at /profile/ User has no customer

Tags: python, django

I have created the user Customer model. I migrated the model to syn with the database. However I am getting an error of User has no customer.
click to profile page through http://127.0.0.1:8000/profile But after adding profile code for every user I am getting the below error

Here is my code

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


# Create your models here.



class Customer(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True, blank=True)

  


    def __str__(self):
        return self.full_name




class  CustomerProfileView(TemplateView):
      template_name = "app/CustomerProfile.html"


     

      def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        customer = self.request.user.customer
        context['customer'] = customer
        orders = Order.objects.filter(cart__customer=customer).order_by("-id")
        context["orders"] = orders
        return context
```

Comment: As the error says, you use a `User` object for which there is no related `Customer` object.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you use a `User` object for which there is no related `Customer` object.

You thus have to construct a `Customer` record for all users that have no `Customer`. You can for example do this in a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/writing-migrations/#data-migrations-and-multiple-databases) with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty app_name
```

in the data migration you can then create a `Customer` for every user *without* a `Customer`:

```
from django.db import migrations

def create_customers(apps, schema_editor):
    Customer = apps.get_model('app_name', 'Customer')
    User = apps.get_model('auth', 'User')
    customers = [
        Customer(user=user, full_name=None, address=None)
        for user in User.objects.filter(customer=None)
    ]
    Customer.objects.bulk_create(customers)

class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('app_name', '1234_some_migration'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunPython(create_customers),
    ]
```

and then run the migration to construct customer for all already existing users.